# Exact reason for a person to become mentally disordered due to wrong practices while kundalini awakening?

Tags: rebirth, human, kundalini

If kundalini awakening practices are supervised by a guru then it will be fruitful and there will be no negative effects.

But, we generally hear that if it is practiced without a guru and in any wrong way then it will lead to mental illness. It can be observed in modern research articles also.

Is the scriptural reason for such mental illness unique or not?

If unique then what is the exact reason? Is it due to the sudden knowledge(experience) of all her previous lives?

Comment: In my personal opinion it is because Pranic body or Prananamaya Kosha becomes disturbed on wrong practices of Yoga. Please refer to Raja Yoga of Swami Vivekananda